# Load Big File into TextInput without blocking UI (python kivy)

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, kivy, python-multithreading

I need to load a big file into a [TextInput](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html) in a python GUI app built with [kivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kivy_(framework)). What is the most efficient way to do this without blocking the UI?

For the sake of this example, I'm using a file named `big_file.txt`. [War And Peace (the book)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_and_Peace) is big: 3.3 MB in plaintext, available from Project Gutenberg here:

- https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2600.txt.utf-8

Save that file to some directory:

```
wget -O big_file.txt https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2600.txt.utf-8
```

Consider the following simplified application named `main.py` and located in the same directory as `big_file.txt`

```
import time

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.count = 0
        layout = BoxLayout()

        # add the label
        self.label1 = Label(id='label1', text='0')
        layout.add_widget(self.label1)

        # add the button
        layout.add_widget( Button(text='Increment', on_release=self.increment) )

        # add the textinput
        self.textinput1 = TextInput(text='Click button to load file.')
        layout.add_widget(self.textinput1)

        # add the button
        layout.add_widget( Button(text='Load File', on_release=self.load_file) )

        return layout

    def load_file(self, *args):
        start = time.time()
        print( "loading file" )
        with open( 'big_file.txt' ) as big_file:
            self.textinput1.text = big_file.read()
        end = time.time()
        print( "finished loading file in " + str(end-start) + " seconds" )

    def increment(self, *args):
        self.count+=1
        self.label1.text = str(self.count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

This kivy application has:

1. An "Increment" Label
2. An "Increment" Button
3. A TextInput
4. A "Load File" Button

The problem is that it takes ~15 seconds to `read()` the 3.3 MB `big_file.txt`. And during that time, the UI is blocked.

For example, after clicking the `Load File` button, the user can't click the `Increment` button for ~15 seconds -- until the file is finished being read by the `load_file()` function.

[image: screen capture of execution with UI locked for 15 seconds while loading the file]

How can I efficiently load the contents of the kivy `TextInput` with `big_file.txt` without blocking the UI?

Comment: I doubt that the read takes 15 seconds. The time is probably spent in updating the `TextInput` itself. You might consider using a `ProgressBar`, or just setting the `TextInput` text to something like "Please Wait".

Comment: You're right. I separated the file read and update of the `TextInput`'s `text` into two lines, and it took 0.025 seconds to read the file. Why does it take so long to update the TextInput? Is there a more efficient widget to be used here? Maybe one that loads the content you scroll or something?

Comment: Do you need the functionality of a `TextInput`?

Comment: I just need the user to be able to scroll around and view the text and select & copy bits of it to their clipboard. But I also tried with a `Label` and it was just as slow to update the text contents of a `Label` as it is to update the text contents of a `TextInput` (actually, it causes a segfault if it's too long [3 MB is too long for a label it seems])

Comment: Note: Kivy v2.1.0 (released 2022-03-06) says in the release notes that it adds "TextInput loading time optimization for large texts" https://github.com/kivy/kivy/releases/tag/2.1.0

Comment: Update: I updated to Kivy v2.1.0, and I saw only minor speed improvements in the original code shown above; it still takes ~12 seconds to load. afaict, the changes were only optimizations that improve the speed when there's lots of repetition in the text, something like compression

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `RecycleView`, which is designed for handling large amounts of data. Here is a modified version of your code that uses a `RecycleView`:

```
import threading
import time

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class RV(RecycleView):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''
<MyLabel@Label>:
    halign: 'center'
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: dp(25)
    text_size: self.size
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'MyLabel'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(25)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.count = 0
        layout = BoxLayout()

        # add the label
        self.label1 = Label(text='0', size_hint_x=0.1)
        layout.add_widget(self.label1)

        # add the button
        layout.add_widget( Button(text='Increment', on_release=self.increment, size_hint_x=0.1))

        # add the RecycleView
        self.rv = RV(size_hint_x=0.7)
        layout.add_widget(self.rv)

        # add the button
        layout.add_widget( Button(text='Load File', on_release=self.load_file, size_hint_x=0.1))

        return layout

    def load_file(self, *args):
        threading.Thread(target=self.actual_load, daemon=True).start()

    def actual_load(self):
        start = time.time()
        print( "loading file" )
        with open( 'big_file.txt' ) as big_file:
            text = big_file.read()
        end = time.time()
        print( "finished loading file in " + str(end-start) + " seconds" )
        lines = []
        start = time.time()
        for line in text.splitlines(keepends=False):
            lines.append({'text': line})
        end = time.time()
        print("finished loading lines in " + str(end-start) + " seconds")
        self.rv.data = lines
        
    def increment(self, *args):
        self.count+=1
        self.label1.text = str(self.count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

This uses a `Label` for each line of text. The `RecycleView` creates a fixed number of `Labels`, and just reuses them as you scroll.

Comment: Wow, that's very fast! But unfortunately with this the user cannot select & copy the text to their clipboard :( Even the `SelectableRecycleBoxLayout` in kivy's documentation doesn't allow the user to select chunks of the text (only select the whole widget itself; in this case a label per line of text) https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html

Comment: There's a pretty big gap here between each line. How do you fix that so that there is the same space between each label in the RecycleView as you'd see in a normal text editor?

Comment: You can adjust the `height` of the `MyLabel` and the `default_size` of the `RecycleBoxLayout`.

Comment: It could be that the `splitlines()` method is creating blank lines, since it splits lines based on a several different characters.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72935115/kivy-recycleview-of-labels-without-clipping-text-or-huge-spaces-between

Answer (score 0):

The `read()` isn't actually what's slow. What's slow is the call to update the `TextInput.text` with a lot of data.

### Threaded Solution

You can prevent from locking the UI by creating a background thread that runs asynchronously

```
import time, threading

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.update_textinput1_bg = None
        layout = BoxLayout()

        # add the label
        self.label1 = Label(text='0')
        layout.add_widget(self.label1)

        # add the button
        layout.add_widget(
         Button(text='Increment',   on_release=self.increment)
        )

        # add the textinput
        self.textinput1 = TextInput(
         text='Click    button to load file.',
         readonly=True
        )
        layout.add_widget(self.textinput1)

        # add the button
        layout.add_widget(
         Button(text='Load  File', on_release=self.load_file)
        )

        return layout

    # function that's called when the "Load File" button is pressed
    def load_file(self, *args):

        # is there already a thread running attempting to update the textinput?
        if self.update_textinput1_bg != None:
            # a thread is already running; tell the user to be patient

            self.textinput1.text = "Still Loading File. Please be patient."

        else:
            # no background thread is running yet; start one now

            start = time.time()
            print( "loading file" )
            self.textinput1.text = "Loading File. Please wait.."

            with open( 'big_file.txt' ) as big_file:
                file_contents = big_file.read()

            end = time.time()
            print( "finished loading file in " + str(end-start) + " seconds" )

            # we use treading.Thread() instead of multiprocessing.Process
            # because it can update the widget's contents directly without
            # us having to pass data in-memory between the child process.
            # Con: We can't kill threads, so it should only be used for
            # short-running background tasks that won't get stuck
            self.update_textinput1_bg = threading.Thread(
             target = self.update_textinput1,
             args   = (file_contents,)
            )

            self.start = time.time()
            self.update_textinput1_bg.start()

            # Register the update_textinput1_tick() function as a callback to be
            # executed every second, and we'll use that to update the UI with a
            # status message from the update_textinput1() thread and check to see
            # if it finished running
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_textinput1_tick, 1)

    # very simple function that updates the contents of the TextInput
    # this is intended to be called in a background Thread so the UI doesn't
    # get locked when "contents" is very large
    def update_textinput1( self, contents, *args ):
        self.textinput1.text = contents

    # callback function that's executed every ~1 second after being secheduled
    # by load_file()
    def update_textinput1_tick( self, dt ):
        print( "called update_textinput1_tick()" )

        # is the background thread still running?
        if not self.update_textinput1_bg.is_alive():
            # the background thread finished running; calculate runtime and
            # unschedule this callback function from being called every second
            end = time.time()
            print( "finished udpdating widget text in " + str(end-self.start) + " seconds" )

            self.update_textinput1_bg = None
            Clock.unschedule( self.update_textinput1_tick )

    # increase the integer displayed in the text of the label widget by one
    def increment(self, *args):
        self.count+=1
        self.label1.text = str(self.count)

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Here's an example execution. Note that it takes:

1. less that 0.2 seconds to read from the file, and
2. over 18 seconds to update the `TextInput`

```
user@buskill:~/tmp/kivy_file_textinput$ /tmp/kivy_appdir/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 main.py 
...
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
...
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.8 (default, Jul  4 2020, 10:00:57) 
[GCC 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)]
...
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
loading file
finished loading file in 0.01690673828125 seconds
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
called update_textinput1_tick()
finished udpdating widget text in 18.336608171463013 seconds
```

### Kivy v2.1.0 TextInput Improvements

Note that last year (in 2021), Kivy made some improvements to the slow loading of large data into a `TextInput`. These were released earlier this year (2022-03-06) in Kivy v2.1.0.

- [Kivy v2.1.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/releases/tag/2.1.0)
- [Issue #7642: TextInput loading time optimisation for large texts](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/7642)

That said, these optimizations appear to be pretty limited. I tested the original code example in both Kivy v1.11.1 (~15 seconds to load the data into the `TextInput`) and v2.1.0 (~12 seconds)

### Why is it so slow?

I mentioned this to issue to the Kivy developers in the link above, and [Gabriel Pettier (tshirtman) provided some insight](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/7642#issuecomment-1180971474).

Using `py-spy top -- python main.py`, you can profile the code and get something like this

```
  %Own   %Total  OwnTime  TotalTime  Function (filename)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  0.00%   0.00%    3.53s    16.71s   _create_line_label (kivy/uix/textinput.py)
  0.00%   0.00%    3.10s    22.70s   _refresh_text (kivy/uix/textinput.py)
  0.00%   0.00%    2.75s    10.12s   refresh (kivy/core/text/__init__.py)
  0.00%   0.00%    2.23s     6.13s   render (kivy/core/text/__init__.py)
  0.00%   0.00%    1.47s     2.32s   _get_font_id (kivy/core/text/text_sdl2.py)
  0.00%   0.00%    1.39s     3.71s   get_extents (kivy/core/text/text_sdl2.py)
  0.00%   0.00%    1.22s     1.64s   __init__ (kivy/core/text/__init__.py)
  0.00%   0.00%    1.11s     1.11s   __init__ (kivy/weakmethod.py)
```

Or produce a flame graph with `py-spy top -- python main.py`

[image]

This shows that the majority of the time is actually spent trying to figure out how wide each line needs to be, which is especially evident at how much the UI locks-up when you resize the window.

> so almost all the time is spent in `_refresh_text` unsurprisingly, and `_create_line_label` in it.
>
> My guess, looking at the code from `_create_line_label` is that most of the time is spent looking for the ideal length of the line, while we start with the logical line length if it's too long, we cut it in half, until it fits and then grows again (half the length) until it does't fit anymore, etc, following a bisection until the stop is less than 2. Any improvement to the initial guess of the line's length could make a significant difference, for example, just by enlarging the window of the example, so most logical lines fit in one display line, the rendering time was cut by more than 50%.
>
> Another idea could be to be able to compute how many words of the line can fit, without rendering the full line, that could be achieved by rendering + caching each unique word encountered, with line options as well (font, etc), so the words texture could be looked up from cache, adding their width until we don't fit the current line anymore, allowing us to either render the line from these words at this point, or reworking the rendering system so a line can just use these textures directly through multiple rectangle instructions, in this technique it would be important to properly keep track of the space between words as well, which depends on the specific character(s) used.
>
> I'm sure there is research about how to do these things efficiently as well, that could be worth looking into (famously, Knuth spent a lot of time on efficient and correct ways to layout text).